# How to install and boot 32-bit Ubuntu on 64-bit UEFI device with no legacy boot option

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, uefi, 64bit, 32bit

Is there any way to install 64-bit UEFI Grub and use it to boot into a 32-bit Ubuntu install? How should the installation process take place? Switching to Legacy BIOS mode is not an option.

Comment: A 64-bit Grub can boot a 32-bit Linux kernel just fine. I don't know how to arrange that with the Ubuntu installer however.